# executing php code on server from React native

Tags: c#, php, react-native, client-server

I'm trying to make a call for a php code on server from react native, and return a value and display it.
The idea that I have an image I want to process it on server save it then return results and the resulted image(I already have a php code on server that run a C# code and give back the results) then showing them on the mobile app . any idea?

Comment: On average [7500 questions are created per minute](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/490701/questions-per-minute) on [so]. This means for your question to get an answer you really should invest some time into taking the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and especially [ask] to create a *proper* *constructive* and *specific* question. A [mcve] usually comes with that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Don't get discouraged by down votes. It doesn't mean we don't like you. It's just a short hand way for people to say that the question needs work. At the rate questions are added shortcuts like that really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a REST API to provide this image?

If you do I use Axios to make http requests.

If you don't, i think fetch has the ability to communicate with a server via TCP.

I suggest you create an API endpoint to provide your image.

Comment: That worked for me, Thanks